# Laravel 8 many to many relationshiop update/delete API (pivot table)

Tags: laravel, api, many-to-many, pivot-table, crud

Hello I need a help with laravel 8 many to many relationship pivot table, when I updating or deleting data in API.
These are my files info.
Firstly I created two tables:
Companies (migration file)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();                
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Contacts (migration file)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

After this created pivot table company_contact (migration file)

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('company_contact', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('company_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('contact_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

Models looks like this:
Company model

```
class Company extends Model{

use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'email'
];

public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class);
}
```

}

Contact model

```
class Company extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'email'
];

public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class);
}
```

}

My routes file

```
Route::apiResource('companies', CompanyController::class);
```

My company controller

```
class CompanyController extends Controller{

 public function index()
{
   return CompanyResource::collection(Company::all());
}   

public function store(CompanyStoreRequest $request)
{
    $company = Company::create($request->validated());  
    $company->contacts()->attach($request->input('contact_id'));          

    return new CompanyResource($company);
}

public function show(Company $company)
{
    //
}

public function update(CompanyStoreRequest $request,Company $company)
{
    $contacts = Company::where('id', $company->id)->contacts()->get();    
    $company->contacts()->sync($request->input(['contact_id'])); 
    $company->update($request->validated());       

    return new CompanyResource($company);
}

public function destroy(Company $company)
{
 
}
```

}

Company store request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'], 
        'contact_id' =>['required']
    ];
}
```

company resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    //return parent::toArray($request);
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'contact_count' => $this->contacts()->count()
    ];
}
```

Maybe somebody can help my to write correct store() and destroy() methods in to company controller. For example when I updating company data also I want to add more contacts and to save these contacts id's in the pivot table.
With destroy method, when I delete certain company, also I want automatically delete these id’s in pivot table (relation company with contacts).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can pass the data of the contacts in an array together with the company's, using an array for several contacts and to record with the relationship use a foreach with the attach method, search on it. About the deletion you can use the softDelete, search on it too, it makes the cascade deletion of the items.